# Getting location type by coordinates

Tags: geolocation, gps, location, coordinates, geocoding

I have a problem, that i need to get location type by coordinates. Simple scenario would be this:
1) Getting coordinates
2) Getting location type

By saying "location type" i mean if it is road, water or smth else.
Maybe somebody has any idea how to do that? I use google geocoding in couple projects, but i couldn't find the way it could help me. Maybe there are some other ways to do that?